# What command to review the relationships between tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Let's say I'm given tables in a database and I want to view the table's relationships as in primary keys and foreign keys and relationships among them etc. How should I do this? Sorry if this question is too basic. I hope you guys can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: You can use SHOW KEYS, however this command does so per table. e.g. SHOW KEYS FROM YOUR_TABLE;

Comment: You can query the [`ALL_CONSTRAINTS` table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm) in Oracle. MySQL is bound to have something similar, you'll have to look it up.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? They're completely different beasts.

Comment: In MySQL, you'll want [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html).

Comment: Your SQL (GUI) client usually displays this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle, the table you want is [ALL_CONSTRAINTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm); the mysql equivalent is [INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLE_CONSTRAINTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-constraints-table.html). All the best.